# Cancel All Google Calendar Watch Requests

Tags: google-calendar-api

#### Problem

Due to the haphazard creation and management of watch requests to certain calendar id's, the `resource_id`s for these watch notifications have been lost. In order to cancel the requests, the `resource_id` must be included in the request.

#### Question(s)

- Is there any way to poll Google (using the `channel_id` or through other means) for the missing `resource_id`?
- Is there a way cancel the push request programmatically through other means?
- Is there a way to collectively cancel all active watch requests through the Google developer console?

#### Context

This is being written in node.js but the question really applies to any platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately push notification channels cannot be list or cancelled without the resource ID returned when they were created. Luckily they have a relatively short lifespan, so the problem should go away naturally.